# Setting LOCAL aspell dictionary size

Tags: gnus, flyspell, spell-checking

How to set local (per buffer) dictionary size used by aspell?
[aspell is used by my emacs as "ispell look alike"]

It can be set by `--size=NN` command line option of `aspell`.
I would like to set it via `gnus-posting-styles` per usenet group.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I have considered setting `ispell-extra-args` but it seems to be global. As I understand `ispell-dictionary-alist` does not provide a way for a few setting for one language (e.g. english-basic, english-normal, eglish-huge)

Comment: `eval` in `gnus-posting-styles` in combination with `make-local-variable` on `ispell-extra-args`?